# CSV file, ERROR. Python

Tags: python, csv

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import logging

Buy  = 'Buy'
Sell = 'Sell'

csvFile = 'C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/compu/GFG.csv'

class MovingAverage:
    """
    Parámetros:
    :_data:          CSV con los datos de instrumento.
    :_shortTerm:     Tamaño de plazo largo en días.
    :_longTerm:      Tamaño de plazo corto en días.
    """
    def __init__(self, _data=csvFile, _shortTerm=10, _longTerm=15):
        self.closingPrices = []

        with open(csvFile,'r') as CSVFile:
            reader = csv.reader(CSVFile)
            for row in reader:
                self.closingPrices.append(row[1]) # Tomo los close
        self.closingPrices.pop(0)    # borro primera fila (date)
        self.closingPrices = map(float, self.closingPrices)
        self.data =[]
        self.shortTerm = _shortTerm
        self.longTerm = _longTerm
        self.shortAverage = self.setShortAverage()
        self.longAverage = self.setLongAverage()
        self.lastIndicator = None
        self.init_logging()
```

And then, i have this error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/algotrade/medias.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.closingPrices.append(row[1])    # Tomo los close

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What´s the problem? which is my error?. HELP PLEASE!

Comment: Looks as if ``row`` is empty (or contains less than 2 items) at some point within your loop. Print it and you should see.

Answer (score 0):

some times you don't have any value in `row[1]` you better need to check if there is a value and then `append`

```
for row in reader:
    if row[1]:
        self.closingPrices.append(row[1])
```